# iOS UIPickerView calls numberOfRowsInComponent even UIPickerViewDataSource is not bound

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, uipickerview, uipickerviewdatasource

*Hi, this question is only about for curiosity.*

I have UIPickerView in my controller, delegate is bound from IB and implemented in controller, and also one of UIPickerViewDataSource method is implemented in controller numberOfRowsInComponent. This method get called even dataSource is not bound and implemented completely. I wonder how it's possible? One of my thought is, this method called from background implicitly... My code;

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate {

let titles = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4", "item 5"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return titles.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return titles[row]
}
```

Comment: Have you set delegate for picker view from storyboard??

Comment: yes, in my interface builder, This code is working btw, my question is how numberOfRowsInComponent called even its protocol not implemented

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned in your comment that you have set `delegate`/ `datasource` from `storyboard`, then its equivalent to `pickerView.delegate = self` / `pickerView.datasource = self`.

You can assign `delegate` and `datasource` either by **coding** or from **storyboard**. So in your case you have done it from `storyboard`, so its actually bound with your `pickerView`.

Comment: Ok, i have set delegate from storyboard, but i did not set dataSource neither by code nor storyboard. numberOfRowsInComponent method is a dataSource method, so my question is how this method called even i didn't do anything with dataSource

Comment: Do you have more than one pickerViews ?? Please check if you have not copy pasted the views which have set delegate and datasource already.

Comment: No i have only one pickerview